# Maximum (client request) thread pool size in spring

Tags: threadpool, spring-boot

I am developing application server using spring boot app but now I want to know what is the default maximum (client request) thread pool size in spring and how can I customize that value?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Assuming that you're using embedded Tomcat, Spring Boot provides a property to control the size of the client request thread pool. Its default value is zero which leaves Tomcat to use its default of 200. If you're using Spring Boot 2.3 or later, this property is named [`server.tomcat.threads.max`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.threads.max). In earlier versions of Spring Boot, the property is named [`server.tomcat.max-threads`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-server).

To customise the size of this thread pool you should specify a non-zero value for the property in your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file.

Comment: Thank you. So what if server gets a more requests than that is specified in application.properties or application.yml. I have a assumption that it holds the request is it?

Comment: [..request requires a thread for the duration of that request. If more simultaneous requests are received than can be handled by the currently available request processing threads, additional threads will be created up to the configured maximum (the value of the maxThreads attribute). If still more simultaneous requests are received, they are stacked up inside the server socket created by the Connector, up to the configured maximum (the value of the acceptCount attribute). Any further simultaneous requests will receive "connection refused" errors, until resources are available to process them.

Comment: It's extracted from here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: Could you help here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181576/threadlocal-using-as-context-information-for-rest-api-with-spring-boot

Comment: what will be the maximum thread pool size that tomcat can handle under different jvm sizes? any way to calculate that value

Comment: Can these properties be controlled with code outside of the normal properties file?

Comment: @jocull Yes, they can by using a `ConnectorCustomizer`. Here's how Boot does it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java#L184-L193.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, I have set mine to server.tomcat.max-threads=1 but it just keeps on growing to a point that it crashers my server.

Comment: If it’s growing unbounded it sounds like you have a different problem. If the default configuration was being used the number of threads would be capped at 200. I’d recommend asking a new question with a minimal examplenthat reproduces the behaviour you have described.

Comment: from springboot 2.3 use server.tomcat.threads.max

Answer (score 58):

As `server.tomcat.max-threads` is deprecated since Springboot 2.3, now use `server.tomcat.threads.max` in your Spring `application.properties`. Default is 200.

Comment: you should point for which version of spring boot it is acceptible. for 2.2.1 this is wrong.

Comment: I think the best is to consult the official reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.web